# Betta's at bottom of tank duplicates

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

We have a lot of Betta's lying at the bottom of their tanks questions. [23 to be exact.](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?q=betta%20bottom%20tank%20is%3Aquestion)

Any one care to wade in on which may be duplicates and the selection of good dupe targets?

Comment: Which 22 to mark as duplicates and which 1 to call the master answer? (It's my first week I just want to make sure I understand)

Comment: @SAMA not all of them will be the same duplicate - there will be some that are the same and X and some that will be the same as Y - yes and to find the masters - and how many masters we need. and welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I help my betta who is laying at the bottom of his tank?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5865/how-can-i-help-my-betta-who-is-laying-at-the-bottom-of-his-tank)

[Is my betta dying/sick or just sleeping?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/is-my-betta-dying-sick-or-just-sleeping)

These have good/decent answers, the second one would need to have the question formatted better. Husbandry is your number 1 issue with Betas as people who buy them are provided with minimal care instructions (led to believe they can be healthy in a glass jar).

Comment: I went through them all and used these as dupe targets

Comment: @YvetteColomb: [This Q](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19688/how-much-water-do-betta-fish-need) was also marked as a dup... but I'm not sure it really was the right call.

Comment: @Roflo I agree, it's reopened, thanks for the ping.